# Prove that |A/∼| = |B|.

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

> Suppose that $f : A \to B$ is a surjective function. Define the following relation on $A$:
>   $$ a_1 \sim a_2 \text{ if and only if } f(a_1) = f(a_2).$$
>   Show that this is an equivalence relation. Denote by $A/\sim$ the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$. Prove that $|A/\sim| = |B|$.

I find it difficult to get started, is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Remember that the definition of an equivalence relation consists of three parts: reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. Do you understand the meaning of each of these concepts? Which one do you have an idea how to prove? (Hint: reflexivity should not be too hard if you know what it means in this context)

Comment: For the second part, prove there exists a surjection from the set $ A /  \sim$ to the set $B$, and a surjection from $B$ to the set $ A /\sim$. This suffices to prove the cardinalities are equal.